# How can I use the Linux terminal to pipe only parts of program input concatenated with hard strings?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, pipe

I understand that I can use xargs like this:

`echo "-i inputfile.raw -o outputfile.jpg" | xargs -t ./myprogram`

However, I am fuzz-testing the application and I have a fuzzer which works like this:

`echo "some text" | myfuzzer`
Output: "@om3 t9gxt"

In other words, my fuzzer takes a string and it performs some permutations on it and then outputs a randomized version of it.

The trick is, I need to redirect "-i inputfile.raw -o outputfile.jpg" THROUGH myfuzzer so that it is mutated, BUT, I need to KEEP the -o, -i, .raw, and .jpg parts... And finally pass the output to myprogram like this:

`echo "-i inpu$@tfifsa4le.raw -o outpuF$tfFAFAile.jpg" | xargs -t ./myprogram`

So I need some way to specify that I only want the file names to be directed through myfuzzer, but not the aforementioned extensions and flags, otherwise they will get permuted too and myprogram won't recognize the arguments unless they have the right flags and extensions... But still reconstruct a string to feed into myprogram.

How can I do this using Bash?

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use `read` in a sub shell

```
echo "inputfile outputfile" | myfuzzer | (read -a arg; echo "-i ${arg[0]}.raw -o ${arg[1]}.jpg" )
```